# Failed to export spans when using opentelemetry-collector-contrib

Tags: java, spring-boot, open-telemetry, jaeger

I made a spring boot app and used Jaeger and otel to trace it, I used this [guide](https://betterprogramming.pub/distributed-tracing-with-opentelemetry-spring-cloud-sleuth-kafka-and-jaeger-939e35f45821) as a reference, only using jaeger-all-in-one and otel-collector in the docker compose and running the java application separately.

I extracted the IP address from the otel collector container and used the following in application.properties

```
spring.sleuth.otel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://OTEL_ADDRESS_FROM_DOCKER:4317
```

It is working and I can see traces in the jaeger ui page.

Then trying out SPM of jaeger and used [this](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/tree/main/docker-compose/monitor) as a guide.

Removing the microsim entry in the docker compose and running it, extracting the otel-collector IP since it's a new container and running the java application again, I am getting this error instead:

```
Failed to export spans. The request could not be executed. Full error message: Failed to connect to /OTEL_ADDRESS_FROM_DOCKER:4317
```

The difference from the two docker compose is the one from monitoring demo uses opentelemetry-collector-contrib because it uses a custom config file for metrics.